# Как из изображения 100х100 получить новое изображение 200х200, не изменяя размера оригинального?

Tags: php, kohana

Здравствуйте, подскажите, у меня есть, к примеру, изображение размером 100х100, как мне получить новое изображение 200х200, не изменяя размера оригинального изображения, т.е. увеличить как бы сам слой картинки, к примеру слой 200х200 а картинка в нем 100х100 (по центру).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На черную картинку 200х200 наложить нужное изображение методом watermark, больше ничего стандартным модулем сделать не получится, придется его дорабатывать или использовать GD

Comment: лучше imagemagick

Comment: @zenden2k лучше просто avalanche123/imagine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$pic_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image);
$pic_new = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
$bgColor = imagecolorallocate($pic_new, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($pic_new, 0, 0, $bgColor);
imagecopy($pic_new, $pic_src, 50, 50, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

В Kohan'е ЕМНИП можно и GD, и ImageMagick использовать, можно что-то типа такого дописать:

```
class Image extends Kohana_Image {

    public static ubercrop($new_width, $new_height) {
      ... код выше ...
    }
}
```